# Rails 4: How to set a default for a custom data type?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Rails 4.2 + MySQL 5.7 setup. I've created a custom data type for native JSON columns, which works fine, with one problem - if I set a default, it's not persisted.

Specifically, if I set the default, the attribute will be set correctly on instantiation, but on instance save, the field will not recognized as changed, so it won't be saved.

This is the data type definition (in a simplified form):

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Type
    class Json < Type::Value
      include Type::Mutable
      def type
        :json
      end

      def type_cast_for_database(value)
        case value
        when Hash
          value.to_json
        else
          raise "type_cast_for_database not supported: #{value.inspect}"
        end
      end

      def type_cast(value)
        case value
        when nil
          {}
        when ::Hash
          value
        else
          raise "type_cast not supported: #{value.inspect}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, if I define the attribute as:

```
  attribute :jsfield, ActiveRecord::Type::Json.new, default: {}
```

On instantiation, the value will be set, but not saved:

```
  instance = MyModel.new
  instance.jsfield        #=> {}
  instance.save           # the INSERT will not include the attribute :jsfield
```

This is caused by `ActiveRecord::Type::Mutable`:

```
  def changed_in_place?(raw_old_value, new_value)
    raw_old_value != type_cast_for_database(new_value)
  end
```

it does the correct thing, but when a default is set, `raw_old_value` is preset (to `{}` in this case), so ActiveRecord thinks that the value hasn't changed.

I can work this around by allowing nil in `ActiveRecord::Type::Json#Jsontype_cast` - but is this the only solution?
Am I missing something?

Comment: `A \`JSON\` column cannot have a default value.`, see [11.6 The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Comment: Yes; the question is about handling a default Rails-side.